# How to map a class to a jsp tag?

Tags: jsp, class, tags

I see some program, in its jsp code, it has following :


And it will be mapped into a class.
When you put some database object into this tag, it will automatically loop to load the data from database.

I want to know, In Jsp, how to map the JSP tag to a class? Then when there is a such tag, system will know it should load a class to process it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with the following manuals in order to write JSP tags as classes.

- [Designing JSP Custom Tag Libraries](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2000/12/15/jsp_custom_tags.html)
- [Developing JSP Custom Tags](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/WebAppDev3/)
- [Programming Simple Tag Handlers](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnann.html)

For completeness, now you can write jsp tags as special tag files, see [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html)